# When clicking on toggle menu it opens but automatically closes

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the toggle menu it opens properly and then it automatically closes. I don't know why it is happening. I have only a little knowledge of JS.

How can I solve this problem?

### My code

```js
if ($('.nav-menu').length) {
  var $mobile_nav = $('.nav-menu').clone().prop({
    class: 'mobile-nav d-lg-none'
  });
  $('body').append($mobile_nav);
  $('body').prepend('<button type="button" class="mobile-nav-toggle d-lg-none"><i class = "icofont-navigation-menu" > < /i></button > ');
    $('body').append('<div class="mobile-nav-overly"></div>'); $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav-toggle', function(e) {
      $('body').toggleClass('mobile-nav-active');
      $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
      $('.mobile-nav-overly').toggle();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav .drop-down > a', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
      var container = $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle");
      if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
          $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
          $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
          $('.mobile-nav-overly').fadeOut();
        }
      }
    });
  }
  else if ($(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").length) {
    $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").hide();
  }
```

Comment: I made you a snippet Please click [edit] then scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and add relevant frameworks, CSS and HTML

Comment: Edit code and display `HTML` and `CSS`

Answer (score 0):

```
Now its working 
if ($('.nav-menu').length) {

    var $mobile_nav = $('.nav-menu').clone().prop({
      class: 'mobile-nav d-lg-none'
    });

    $('body').append($mobile_nav);
    $('body').prepend('<button type="button" class="mobile-nav-toggle d-lg-none"><i class="icofont-navigation-menu"></i></button>');
    $('body').append('<div class="mobile-nav-overly"></div>');

    $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav-toggle', function (e) {
      $('body').toggleClass('mobile-nav-active');
      $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
      $('.mobile-nav-overly').toggle();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav .drop-down > a', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
      var container = $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle");

      if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
       // I removed the unnecessary code from here
        
      }
    });

  } else if ($(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").length) {
    $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").hide();
  }
```